# AWS SSM Agent registration call cannot be proxied?

Tags: amazon-web-services, proxy, squid, aws-systems-manager

How do I proxy the `amazon-ssm-agent -register` call?

I want to proxy all the `amazon-ssm-agent` traffic in a **local VM** instance through a squid proxy.

When the SSM agent is running, it seems to proxy all traffic (as expected) through squid. However, the initial registration call seems to not be proxied.

**Example:**

**Given** a squid proxy server with the following rules ( */etc/squid/squid.conf* )

```
acl whitelist dstdomain example.com
http_access allow whitelist
```

**And** having configured (`systemctl edit amazon-ssm-agent`) the proxy settings for aws-ssm-agent:

```
[Service]
Environment="http_proxy=http://localhost:3128"
Environment="https_proxy=http://localhost:3128"
Environment="no_proxy=169.254.169.254"
```

**Then** I would expect the following to **fail** because the proxy does not allow access to anything except for `example.com`

```
> amazon-ssm-agent -register -code "abcdefghijklmnop" -id "aaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaa" -region "eu-west-2"
```

**But actually** it bypasses the proxy and registers with AWS successfully (`/var/log/amazon/ssm/amazon-ssm-agent.log`):

```
2019-01-11 14:44:57 DEBUG Start File Watcher On: /etc/amazon/ssm/seelog.xml
2019-01-11 14:44:57 DEBUG Start Watcher on directory: /etc/amazon/ssm
2019-01-11 14:45:55 INFO Successfully registered the instance with AWS SSM using Managed instance-id: mi-0000aa00000a0aaaa0
```

**How can I ensure that the `amazon-ssm-agent -register` call is proxied through squid?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `amazon-ssm-agent -register` call is not run as a service by systemd, so to proxy the `register` call itself, you will have to set/export the proxy properties the usual way.

```
> http_proxy="http://localhost:3128"
> https_proxy="http://localhost:3128"
> amazon-ssm-agent -register -code "abcdefghijklmnop" -id "aaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaa" -region "eu-west-2"
```

Simple. Once you know that that's the case :)